# Missing list of algs in QGIS 2.14 Processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, grass-7.0

I changed my QGIS-version from 2.8 to 2.14. I am very happy that v.net algs (grass7) are available now as part of the processing plugin. But now there is no list of algs inside the modeler - so no possibility of building models that way. If I switch back to the processing-version of QGIS 2.8 it is all working fine, but v.net algs are missing then. I tried to combine both versions of the processing-plugin already, but nothing is working out.

Does anyone have the same issues, and is there any solution for it?